# Apply partially instantiated lemma

Tags: coq

Let us assume that we want to prove the following (totally contrived) lemma.

```
Lemma lem : (forall n0 : nat, 0 <= n0 -> 0 <= S n0) -> forall n, le 0 n.
```

We want to apply `nat_ind` to prove it. Here is a possible proof:

```
Proof.
  intros H n. apply nat_ind. constructor. exact H.
Qed.
```

But why not directly using `H` in the apply tactic, using something like `apply (nat_ind _ _ H)` or `eapply (nat_ind _ _ H)` ? But the first one fails, and the second one hides the remaining goal in an existential variable.

Is it possible in `apply` or its derivatives to skip hypotheses in order to specify the other arguments while keeping them as classic goals in the remainder of the proof ?

Comment: A typo: `intros n H.` should be `intros H n.`

Comment: Looks like Coq doesn't infer a proof term for `P 0` a.k.a. `0 <= 0`, since this works: `apply (nat_ind _ (le_n _) H).`

Comment: @AntonTrunov corrected, thanks.

Comment: @AntonTrunov I do not expect Coq to guess the missing proof (here it is not difficult, but more complex cases can be found). I would like Coq to leave me with one goal: `0 <= 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach (more universal than in my other answer) would be using the `apply ... with ...` construct, like this:

```
intros H n.
apply nat_ind with (2 := H).
```

Here, `2` is referring to the inductive step parameter of `nat_ind` (see the Coq v8.5 reference manual, 8.1.3):

> In a bindings list of the form `(ref_1 := term_1) ... (ref_n := term_n)`, ref is either an ident or a **num**. ... If `ref_i` is some number *n*, this number denotes the *n*-th non dependent premise of the term, as determined by the type of term.

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
intros. refine (nat_ind _ _ H _).
```

then you only have

```
0 <= 0
```

left. Is that useful in your case?

Comment: This is an interesting alternative. If no better idea comes, I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This partial proof

```
intros H n.
apply nat_ind, H.
```

will give you `0 <= 0` as the only subgoal left.

This approach uses the `apply` tactic, but does not answer the question in its generality, since it will work only if you want to instantiate the *last* parameter (which is the case for the example in the question).
Here is quote from the Coq reference manual:

> `apply term_1 , ... , term_n`
>
> This is a shortcut for `apply term_1 ; [ .. | ... ; [ .. | apply term_n ]... ]`, i.e. for the successive applications of `term_(i+1)` on the last subgoal generated by `apply term_i`, starting from the application of `term_1`.

Also, since it's just syntactic sugar, the solution may be considered cheating (and, I guess, abuse of the original intent of the Coq tactics developers) in the context of the question.

Comment: I did not know this variant. Indeed it seems to only solve this particular example. What is the purpose of this syntax in general ?

Comment: I think it's most useful in the case when one has several hypotheses of the form  `H_i : B_i -> B_(i+1)` and one can chain them. So instead of writing: `apply H_n. apply H_(n-1). ... apply H_1.`, one can write `apply H_n, H_(n-1), ... H_1`. Or in a more general case when each `apply` generates only one subgoal, which can be "simplified" further using the next hypothesis/lemma, etc.